# There is a simple Kotlin code example with lambda functions. but it doesn't work like that

Tags: kotlin

Instead of returning an int "10", it returns a weird string like "Function1<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer>"

Source code:

`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println(Bird.a { 10 })
}

class Bird() {

    companion object {

        fun a(b: @JvmSuppressWildcards () -> Int): (Int) -> Int {
            return { b() }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Expected Output Int 10
The output I get is Function1<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not returning an Int, but it's returning a lambda that accepts an Int: (Int) -> Int.
If you want the function to return an Int change the return Type from: `(Int) -> Int` to: `Int` and you will need to change `return { b() }` to `return b()`,

So the final function will be like that:

```
class Bird() {

    companion object {

        fun a(b: @JvmSuppressWildcards () -> Int): Int {
            return b()
        }
    }
}
```

If you still want to get a lambda and you need to get the Int from it, you need to call it like any other function, here you are printing the lambda itself:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println(Bird.a { 10 })
}
```

but you need to call it and pass the Int for it so you can print the result, like that:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println(Bird.a { 10 }(10))
}
```

You need to pass an Int or it will not work but you are not using that Int in your code so you can delete it by changing the return type from `(Int) -> Int` to `() -> Int`.

Or you can use it like that:

```
class Bird() {

    companion object {

        fun a(b: @JvmSuppressWildcards () -> Int): (Int) -> Int {
            return { b() * it } // it is the Int passed to the returned lambda
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if I still want to get a lambda and then get the number Int from lambda?

Comment: @Apelsinovi_sok answer updated, take a look now